# dynamic defaultValue on input type not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input type

```
<input defaultValue={this.getValue(labelName)} type="text" name={labelName} className="form-control" id={labelCateg+':'+labelName}  onChange={(e)=>{this.handleChange(e,labelName)}}/>
```

If i specify the `defaultValue="something"` , it works
when i make it dynamic , on dev tools , it shows the value under `value` attribute but not on the view.

Comment: `defaultValue` will be triggered only when the initial render happens, you need to use controlled components to update it post initial render.

Comment: and how do i do that ?

Comment: Maintain state for your input component, and re-render it when the state gets changed.

Answer (score 1):

Changed it to controlled component . onChange changes the value at the source which indirectly changes the value on the dom on rerender